# Juniper SRX IPSec tunnel to Microsoft Azure Dropping

Tags: azure, ipsec, juniper, srx

I'm a bit stumped and was hoping to find some guidance here.

I've configured an IPSec tunnel to Microsoft Azure from my Juniper SRX240 (12.1X44-D45.2). The tunnel works fine but phase 2 drops when there is no traffic running across the tunnel (doesn't matter from which side traffic originates).

I've tried playing around with DPD but Azure doesn't support it. I've also configured VPN monitor to a destination on the other end of the tunnel but this also didn't work. In my "show log kmd" I am seeing P2 no proposal chosen messages after the drop occurs. I should add that phase 1 never drops.

This would be ok but unfortunately I have to statically route the remote ranges over the tunnel and since the tunnel doesn't (and can't) have an IP address, my next hop is st0.2. When phase 2 drops, so does the static route and routing follows the next more specific route. So there's no way to bring the tunnel back up automatically at this time.

I would greatly appreciate any advice or assistance on the matter. I need the tunnel to stay up even when there's no traffic running over it. Please see my config below.

```
set groups GENERIC_GROUP security ike proposal IKE_PROPOSAL authentication-method pre-shared-keys
set groups GENERIC_GROUP security ike proposal IKE_PROPOSAL dh-group group2
set groups GENERIC_GROUP security ike proposal IKE_PROPOSAL authentication-algorithm sha1
set groups GENERIC_GROUP security ike proposal IKE_PROPOSAL encryption-algorithm aes-256-cbc
set groups GENERIC_GROUP security ike proposal IKE_PROPOSAL lifetime-seconds 28800
set groups GENERIC_GROUP security ipsec proposal IPSEC_PROPOSAL protocol esp
set groups GENERIC_GROUP security ipsec proposal IPSEC_PROPOSAL authentication-algorithm hmac-sha1-96
set groups GENERIC_GROUP security ipsec proposal IPSEC_PROPOSAL encryption-algorithm aes-256-cbc
set groups GENERIC_GROUP security ipsec proposal IPSEC_PROPOSAL lifetime-seconds 3600
set groups GENERIC_GROUP security ipsec policy IPSEC_POLICY proposals IPSEC_PROPOSAL
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP interfaces st0 unit 2 family inet
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ike policy IKE_POLICY mode main
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ike policy IKE_POLICY proposals IKE_PROPOSAL
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ike policy IKE_POLICY pre-shared-key ascii-text omitted
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ike gateway IKE_GATEWAY ike-policy IKE_POLICY
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ike gateway IKE_GATEWAY address omitted
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ike gateway IKE_GATEWAY external-interface vlan.457
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ike gateway IKE_GATEWAY version v2-only
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ipsec vpn IPSEC_VPN bind-interface st0.2
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ipsec vpn IPSEC_VPN vpn-monitor optimized
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ipsec vpn IPSEC_VPN vpn-monitor destination-ip 192.168.183.2
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ipsec vpn IPSEC_VPN ike gateway IKE_GATEWAY
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ipsec vpn IPSEC_VPN ike ipsec-policy IPSEC_POLICY
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security ipsec vpn IPSEC_VPN establish-tunnels immediately
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security policies from-zone AZURE_ZONE to-zone CUSTOMER_TRUST policy default-allow match source-address AZURE_ZONE-RANGE
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security policies from-zone AZURE_ZONE to-zone CUSTOMER_TRUST policy default-allow match destination-address CUSTOMER-PRIVATES
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security policies from-zone AZURE_ZONE to-zone CUSTOMER_TRUST policy default-allow match application any
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security policies from-zone AZURE_ZONE to-zone CUSTOMER_TRUST policy default-allow then permit
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone INTERNET interfaces vlan.457 host-inbound-traffic system-services ike
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone INTERNET interfaces vlan.457 host-inbound-traffic system-services ssh
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone INTERNET interfaces vlan.457 host-inbound-traffic system-services snmp
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone INTERNET interfaces vlan.457 host-inbound-traffic system-services telnet
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone INTERNET interfaces vlan.457 host-inbound-traffic system-services ping
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone AZURE_ZONE address-book address AZURE_ZONE-RANGE 192.168.183.0/24
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone AZURE_ZONE interfaces st0.2 host-inbound-traffic system-services all
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone CUSTOMER_TRUST address-book address CUSTOMER-PRIVATE-RANGE1 10.0.0.0/8
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone CUSTOMER_TRUST address-book address CUSTOMER-PRIVATE-RANGE2 172.16.0.0/12
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone CUSTOMER_TRUST address-book address CUSTOMER-PRIVATE-RANGE3 192.168.0.0/16
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone CUSTOMER_TRUST address-book address-set CUSTOMER-PRIVATES address CUSTOMER-PRIVATE-RANGE1
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone CUSTOMER_TRUST address-book address-set CUSTOMER-PRIVATES address CUSTOMER-PRIVATE-RANGE2
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone CUSTOMER_TRUST address-book address-set CUSTOMER-PRIVATES address CUSTOMER-PRIVATE-RANGE3
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP security zones security-zone CUSTOMER_TRUST interfaces vlan.456 host-inbound-traffic system-services all
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP routing-instances CUSTOMER_GROUP routing-options static route 0.0.0.0/0 next-hop 1.1.1.1
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP routing-instances CUSTOMER_GROUP routing-options static route 192.168.183.0/24 next-hop st0.2
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP routing-instances CUSTOMER_GROUP routing-options static route 192.168.0.0/16 next-hop 172.31.0.2
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP routing-instances CUSTOMER_GROUP routing-options static route 10.0.0.0/8 next-hop 172.31.0.2
set groups CUSTOMER_GROUP routing-instances CUSTOMER_GROUP routing-options static route 172.16.0.0/12 next-hop 172.31.0.2
```

This is what the kmd logs look like.

```
[Jul  9 13:56:40]Added (spi=0xffa48b1d, protocol=0) entry to the spi table
[Jul  9 13:56:40]Construction NHTB payload for  local:1.1.1.1, remote:2.2.2.2 IKEv2 P1 SA index 1241218 sa-cfg IPSEC_VPN
[Jul  9 13:56:40]Peer router vendor is not Juniper. Not sending NHTB payload for sa-cfg IPSEC_VPN
[Jul  9 13:56:40]ikev2_packet_allocate: Allocated packet db4000 from freelist
[Jul  9 13:56:40]Received authenticated notification payload No proposal chosen from local:1.1.1.1 remote:2.2.2.2 IKEv2 for P1 SA 1241218
[Jul  9 13:56:40]ikev2_decode_packet: [db4000/dfe400] Received packet: HDR, N(NO_PROPOSAL_CHOSEN)
[Jul  9 13:56:40]ikev2_state_child_initiator_in: [db4000/dfe400] Error: Mandatory payloads (SAr,Ni,TSi,TSr) missing
[Jul  9 13:56:40]ikev2_process_notify: [db4000/dfe400] Received error notify No proposal chosen (14)
[Jul  9 13:56:40]ikev2_state_error: [db4000/dfe400] Negotiation failed because of error No proposal chosen (14)
[Jul  9 13:56:40]IPSec negotiation failed for SA-CFG IPSEC_VPN for local:1.1.1.1, remote:2.2.2.2 IKEv2. status: No proposal chosen
[Jul  9 13:56:40]   P2 ed info: flags 0x82, P2 error: Error ok
[Jul  9 13:56:40]IPSec SA done callback with sa-cfg NULL in p2_ed. status: No proposal chosen
[Jul  9 13:56:42]ikev2_packet_allocate: Allocated packet db4400 from freelist
[Jul  9 13:56:42]ikev2_decode_packet: [db4400/dfe400] Setting ed pkt ctx from VR id 4 to VR id 4)
[Jul  9 13:56:42]ikev2_decode_packet: [db4400/dfe400] Received packet: HDR
[Jul  9 13:56:42]ikev2_packet_allocate: Allocated packet db4800 from freelist
[Jul  9 13:56:43]ikev2_packet_allocate: Allocated packet db4c00 from freelist
```

Like I said, it works perfectly well until there's no traffic and I have no idea what else to try.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

That issue sounds like an issue I had in a IPSec VPN tunnel between Vyatta and Juniper SRX.

Have you tried to configure in your juniper and in azure the dead peer detection under the IKE configuration in the first phase of the VPN negotiation?

In Juniper I know that it is enabled by default but for example in Vyatta I had to configure manually and it looks like something like that:

```
    ike-group <IKE-GROUP> {
        dead-peer-detection {
            action restart
            interval 15
            timeout 30
        }
        lifetime 3600
        proposal 1 {
            encryption aes256
            hash sha1
        }
        proposal 2 {
            encryption aes256
            hash sha1
        }
    }
```

Please let me know if it does work for you.

Saul